# Many combinations multi-line conditions of the 'if' in a loop

Tags: python, algorithm, if-statement, networkx

Here is a fragment of the code responsible for creating the graph and its edges, depending on whether the edge exists and the condition that validates the shortest paths:

```
for q in range(len(aaa_binary)):

    if len(added)!=i+1:
       g.add_nodes_from (aaa_binary[q])
       t1 = (aaa_binary[q][0],aaa_binary[q][1])
       t2 = (aaa_binary[q][1],aaa_binary[q][2])
       t3 = (aaa_binary[q][2],aaa_binary[q][3])
       if g.has_edge(*t1)==False and g.has_edge(*t2)==False and g.has_edge(*t3)==False:
          g.add_edge(*t1)
          g.add_edge(*t2)
          g.add_edge(*t3)
          added.append([aaa_binary[q],'p'+ str(i)])                                                
          for j in range(len(added)):
              if nx.shortest_path(g, added[j][0][0], added[j][0][3])!=added[j][0] or nx.shortest_path(g, aaa_binary[q][0], aaa_binary[q][3])!=aaa_binary[q]:
                 g.remove_edge(*t1)
                 g.remove_edge(*t2)   
                 g.remove_edge(*t3)                                     
                 added.remove([aaa_binary[q],'p'+ str(i)])
                 break

       if g.has_edge(*t1)==False and g.has_edge(*t2)==False and g.has_edge(*t3)==True:
          g.add_edge(*t1)
          g.add_edge(*t2)
          added.append([aaa_binary[q],'p'+ str(i)])                                                
          for j in range(len(added)):
              if nx.shortest_path(g, added[j][0][0], added[j][0][3])!=added[j][0] or nx.shortest_path(g, aaa_binary[q][0], aaa_binary[q][3])!=aaa_binary[q]:
                 g.remove_edge(*t1)
                 g.remove_edge(*t2)                                           
                 added.remove([aaa_binary[q],'p'+ str(i)])
                 break                                            

# ... and then the rest of the False and True possibilities combinations in the `if g.has_edge()'condition.
```

added[] - list of currently valid paths in the form `[[[0, 2, 4, 6], 'p0'], [[0, 2, 4, 1], 'p1'],...]`

aaa_binary[] - list of path combinations to check in the form `[[0, 2, 4, 6], [0, 2, 6, 4], [0, 4, 2, 6],...]`

Loop operation:

The algorithm selects one sublist from the aaa_binary list, then adds nodes to the graph and creates edges. Then the algorithm checks if the given edge exists. If it does not exist, it adds it to the graph, if it exists, it does not add. Then, if the condition of the shortest path is not met, only the newly added edge is removed from the graph. And so until you find the right path from the aaa_binary list.

As you can see only with the four-element sublistors, there are 8 different combinations of False and True in the condition `if g.has_edge ()` in the aaa_binary list, which already makes a technical problem. However, I would like to develop this to check, for example, eight-element paths, and then the combination will be 128! Which is obvious that I can not do it in the current way.
And I care that the loop necessarily adds only non-existent edges, because then it is easier to control the creation of the optimal graph.

Hence my question, is it possible to write such a loop differently and automate it more? I will be very grateful for any comments.

Comment: `Then, if the condition of the shortest path is not met, only the newly added edge is removed from the graph.` : If you do not find the shortest_path, you delete an edge ? Isn't it contradictory ?

Comment: no, because I am looking for such edges with which the shortest path will exist. and if after adding the given edge there is no shortest path, it means that the edge is bad and can not be added, so you have to delete it.

Comment: in addition, it is about removing only the currently checked and added edge. its removal does not destroy the old layout in the graph.

Comment: You are testing the 3 conditions every time (<False, False, False>, then <False, False, True>, then <False, True, False>, ...), have specifics scheme for each, and want to avoid having the redundant if g_edge() condition ?

Comment: I have a solution to avoid the 8 different combinations of False and True, but I don't think this is your question, right ? I didn't understand correctly the "eight-element path". :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I've completely understood your doubt, but that's what I mean. because at the stage of checking a given sublist from aaa_binary I have to somehow recognize if any of the edges from this sub-list did not exist, so that if the condition is not met, I do not remove existing ones, I just delete newly added ones.

Comment: it is possible that this will be a good solution, because now I check the sublisty in the form, for example [0,1,2,3], i.e. the edges (0,1), (1,2), (2,3). hence the three combinations of True and False. However, I would like to study eight-element sublistels, for example [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], i.e. with seven edges. I have made a mistake in the post above, i.e. not 256 cases from True and False, only 128 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
added_now = []
for edge in (t1,t2,t3):
    if not g.has_edge(*edge):
        g.add_edge(*edge)
        added_now.append(edge)
added.append([aaa_binary[q],'p'+ str(i)])                                                
for j in range(len(added)):
    if nx.shortest_path(g, added[j][0][0], added[j][0][3])!=added[j][0] or nx.shortest_path(g, aaa_binary[q][0], aaa_binary[q][3])!=aaa_binary[q]:
       for edge in added_now:
           g.remove_edge(*edge)                                  
       added.remove([aaa_binary[q],'p'+ str(i)])
```

You just want to do the same for each edge that wasn't added.

Answer (score 1):

Does this solution suits you ?

- It doesn't block you from your 4-elem paths. It adjusts to the len of the current `aaa_binary[q]`. If you want to choose a n-elem paths, it should be easily modifiable. :)
- It doesn't have a non-ending list of if.

  for q in range(len(aaa_binary)):

  ```
  if len(added)!=i+1:
      g.add_nodes_from(aaa_binary[q])
      #   Instead of having hard-coded variable, make a list.
      tn = []
      for idx in range(0, len(aaa_binary[q]) - 1):
          #   Linking the current elem, to the next one.
          #   The len() - 1 avoids the iteration on the last elem,
          #   that will not have another elem after it.
          tn.append((aaa_binary[q][idx], aaa_binary[q][idx + 1]))

      #   Instead of checking each and every case, try to make your
      #   task 'general'. Here, you want to add the edge that doesn't exist.
      indexSaver = []
      for index, item in enumerate(tn):
          if g.has_edge(*item):
              g.add_edge(*item)

              #   This line is here to keep in mind which item we added,
              #   Since we do not want to execute `.has_edge` multiple times.
              indexSaver.append(index)


      #   This line is quite unclear as we do not know what is 'added',
      #   neither 'i' in your code. So I will let it as is.
      added.append([aaa_binary[q], 'p' + str(i)])

      #   Now that non-existent edges have been added...
      #   I don't understand this part. So we will just modify the [3]
      #   index that was seemingly here to specify the last index.
      for j in range(len(added)):
          lastIndex = len(added) - 1
          if nx.shortest_path(g, added[j][0][0], added[j][0][lastIndex])!=added[j][0] or nx.shortest_path(g, aaa_binary[q][0], aaa_binary[q][lastIndex])!=aaa_binary[q]:
              #   On the same logic of adding edges, we delete them.
              for idx, item in enumerate(tn):
                  if idx in indexSaver:
                      g.remove_edge(*item)
              added.remove([aaa_binary[q], 'p' + str(i)])
              break
  ```